# how to refresh the page if php retrurns true

Tags: php, ajax

im in a bit of a weird situation.

I have page which displays rows of a database table. Each row has 2 fields which are both numbers and are being updated every few seconds using ajax, I also have other fields from each row in the databse. I have set the page to only show the row if field A is greater than field B.

This works when the user first visits the page. However as soon as field A is less than Field B the two fields dissapear as they are supposed to but the rest of the fields from the row stay.

What I thought was if I could get the page to refresh when field B is greater than field A than the page would work as it is supposed to.

What would I need to do to refresh the page if field B is greater than field A?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can't you just remove the whole row from the table? Like `document.getElementById('row_to_remove').parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('row_to_remove'));`?

Comment: you can refresh the page by window.location = window.location. but this is not the right solution I feel as you can do that in Ajax itself if you debug better.

Answer (score 0):

Use window.location.href, but you'll need to add a dummy number to force a refresh in most browsers:

```
// After you conditions to check if B > A then do this:
window.location.href = window.location.href + "?refreshme=" + (new Date());
```

You'll want to put some logic in there so that if you already have a url with ? in it you use & instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can always print this if B is greater than A:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://www.yoursite.com/">
```

That should help.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hiding the cells (I'm assuming you are hiding or removing the TDs) you could hide their parentElelment. Which would presumably be the TR.

```
myTD_Dom_Element.parentNode
```

But to specifically answer your question, you could do...

```
window.location.reload()
```